# How Would I Convert an Integer to Char* C++

Tags: c++, integer, char

I have a fork process that adds 2 numbers and returns an integer.

The only problem is that the sum is an integer and in order to keep returning the array I need a char* pointing to that integer.

Any ideas how i could accomplish this in C++; (I cannot use the String.h library)

Edit**

This is the portion of code i'm working with

```
 //process has been completed
else
{
for(int q=0; q<numofProc; q++)
{
wait(&status);
if (WIFEXITED(status))
    {
    value = WEXITSTATUS(status);
temp = (char)(value);
    char* pointer = (char*)temp;
sumArray[sizeSum] = pointer;
sizeSum++;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot use `string.h`? Can you use `std::string`? If not, I am not particularly interested.

Comment: Do you mean you can't use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?  Or the old C-style string functions?

Comment: Also, what have you tried? We're not going to "do this for [you]", especially if you cannot use _any_ actual C++ functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `char*` pointer to point to `int` you just cast your `int*` to `char*`. Like `(char*)intptr`. It doesn't sound like a good `c++` practice to me, though. Make sure you don't return a pointer to local variable to the function.

I assume if you wanted to return pointer to character representation of your integer you would say so.

Comment: so I would set the char* to the address of the integer like char* temp = &integer;

Comment: Something like that. But again, keep in mind, that if `integer` is temporary, you'll have problems trying to dereference pointer.

Comment: The code in your edit isn't likely to work well, as `temp` thing is going to be lost. But, depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may also store the int itself as a pointer. Why don't you make an array of integers, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = 3234;
stringstream ss;
ss << num;

const char *res = ss.str().c_str();
```

Comment: If you return that from the function, you're screwed.

Comment: I spent a lot of time finding the problem in that last line once.